# who is the patent troll suing small companies on 5506866? which inventor sold the rights to them?

Tags: ownership, us5506866, npe

Who is the "Delaware-based" troll suing small companies on [US5506866](http://www.google.com/patents/US5506866) currently?

Who sold the rights to said troll?

Answer (score 1):

From a patent's page on google patents you can click on Search USPTO Assignment Database to get to the USPTO records of all of the assignments from inventor to owner to owner. It is like the recording of a deed. This one's (SIDE-CHANNEL COMMUNICATIONS IN SIMULTANEOUS VOICE AND DATA TRANSMISSION) assignment record is [here](http://assignments.uspto.gov/assignments/q?db=pat&pat=5506866). It looks like it was invented by AT&T and transferred to other AT&T entities, used as collateral for loans to an AT&T spin off and recently sold

by:

Assignor:
PATENT BUSINESS DEVELOPMENT, LLC
Exec Dt:
05/23/2012

to:

Assignee:
CLEARWATER INNOVATIONS, LLC
3411 SILVERSIDE ROAD, SUITE 108
WEBSTER BUILDING
WILMINGTON, DELAWARE 19810
Correspondent:
M. VANESSAH MELTON
800 S. AUSTIN AVE., SUITE 200
GEORGETOWN, TX 78626-5845